# What does 0.0.0.0/0 mean?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, bind, cidr, chrony

For example in an 'allow' statement in BIND or in Chrony config files.

Does **allow 0.0.0.0/0** mean allowing *any clients* or allowing *no clients*?

My question isn't about the specific programs, but just generally what is the correct interpretation of this CIDR notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It literally means *all or any hosts* - 99.99% of the time.

The only exception I can provide at hand is the *whitelist* of Cisco routers, where such "zero whitelist" means negating all hosts. It is a pretty specific case, though.